# Is there a way to use the Windows Form table in a Razor view cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datatable

I've been wondering is there a way in Razor view to use the windows table(basically i want to use a different table than the standard HTML one so that i can also filter my results automatically with that table rather than using checkboxes or whatsoever for that). I'm quite noob to ASP.net and also to HTML so the question might be a bit stupid but i honestly have no clue and i'm having trouble finding the information on the internet.

Greetings and thanks in advance,

Marijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms and ASP.NET MVC absolutely different technologies. All you see as result of ASP.NET MVC is browser, and browser shows HTML. So the answer is NO, there is no way to use Windows Forms table in ASP.NET MVC.
But it's not bad. There are a lot of examples of Tables for ASP.NET MVC. Try http://www.jtable.org/. It's not perfect, but something to start.